# Monitor all process spawn and exit events on windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, process

I have to implement an application/service for Windows 7 or 8 that will keep track of all the processes that were spawned during a timespan and also their exit times.

Can someone please let me know if Windows OS provides any callback mechanism which will be called whenever a new process has been created and exited.
Idea is to show trend of usage of different applications through out the day or timespan.

This application is not intended for any marketplace or commercial use but for my own use. So any kind of suggestion will be very useful.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed

Comment: See how [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) makes job.

Answer (score 0):

Even such *professional* tools like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) are working will a poll mechanism (can be configured through View - Update Speed).

So i would say there exists no such mechanism and all you can do is regularly retrieve the list of all running process and compare it with the list you retrieved beforehand.

Comment: Maybe he's ok with a fast enough polling: `EnumProcesses` or `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`. Otherwise I think he needs a kernel filter.

Comment: Hi Liviu, can you please elaborate a bit on "kernel filter" you mentioned. Thx